# OAuth2 Access Token Response

Tags: oauth, oauth-provider

Quick question regarding the OAuth2 Spec, in particular [section 5.1.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-07#section-5.1.5).

Reading that spec, it appears that the response needs to be formatted as JSON regardless of the format requested. Is that the standard or are other formats (i.e. XML) also supported? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From revision 07 of the spec (from the changelog): "Removed multiple formats support, leaving JSON as the only format." [Oauth2 Spec Document History](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-07#appendix-C)